# Missing linux-modules-extra package on encrypted Ubuntu

Tags: networking, kernel, 22.04

I have Ubuntu with LUKS encryption. After some updates yesterday all was working fine, but upon booting today I had problems that neither monitor was seen nor I could connect to Internet via WiFi (adapter not found). I can't get bootable USB to see my installation due to the encryption. I can access to USB content, but it seems I can't tether Internet connection from my mobile phone. Ethernet cable doesn't help as well.
Some info:

```
lsb-release -a
...
Description: 22.04.2 LTS
...
```

```
uname -r
5.19.0-38-generic
```

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra
dpkg-querry: package linux-modules-extra is not installed ..
```

My guess is that I have to use another PC to download this package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kernel/linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-38-generic
and all the dependencies; move them with USB and . I can't find where to download .deb file. Clicking on *[list of files]* gets me to error page: "No such package in this suite on this architecture."

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Click on the *amd64* and see this download link: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.19/linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-38-generic_5.19.0-38.39~22.04.1_amd64.deb Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed now! I still have to get my monitor back on, but it should be easy with working Internet connection.